# How to Intercept a data-type before deserialization, when it reaches WEB API?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, json.net

We need a mechanism so that when ever a particular data-type (say date-time) reaches Web API, we should be able intercept it & perform some business logic transformation on that data.

> For Response we have been able to achieve it as below, but need your
>   help on how to intercept for requests?

What I tried?
DateTimeConverter class:

```
 public class DateTimeConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return objectType == typeof(DateTime);
        }
        public override bool CanRead
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        public override bool CanWrite
        {
            get
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            var timeUtc = (DateTime)value;
            TimeZoneInfo easternZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
            DateTime easternTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(timeUtc, easternZone);
            writer.WriteValue(easternTime);
        }
        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            // the default deserialization works fine, 
            // but otherwise we'd handle that here
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Register: -

```
 protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        var formatters = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters;
        var jsonFormatter = formatters.JsonFormatter;
        jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new TimeSpanConverter());

        jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new DateTimeConverter());
    }
```